# Java System Time after changing computer clock

Tags: java, clock, systemtime

I would like to get the time in a java app after changing my computer clock.
This doesn't seem to get the correct time.

For example

```
Computer clock reads 1:30pm; new Date() returns 1:30pm
Change computer clock to 12:30pm;
Computer clock reads 12:30pm; new Date() returns 12:30pm
Change computer clock to 1:30pm;
Computer clock reads 1:30pm; new Date() returns 12:30pm
```

Is it possible for my java app to detect this change in clock?

Update: seems to only happen in Chrome...

Comment: If you are using IDE restart it. They may have same jvm instances for both the run.

Comment: I do not want to restart my IDE.

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior in eclipse on Win7 x64 with Java7. Post an SSCCE - this is clearly not expected behavior, because `new Date()` should use the system time and contrary to nanoTime doesn't guarantee monotonicity.

Comment: I am running Java 1.6.0.30.  Does Java 7 fix this issue?

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and we can check. It seems unlikely though that the date API has such a strange bug.

Comment: I have a timer that prints out new Date() every second.  Following the original post, you should get the same results

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Thread that continuosly checks the time after X ms. if the time offset is greater than +-N than what it should be (taking this as other processes may be using the processor so small error may be there) then create an offset for the time. Then create a new date class for yourself and add the offset to get the time.

I dont know if it is completely accurate but it will work in most of the cases

EDIT:
The thread will record the time of the system clock and will go to sleep.

so for example we keep an error raito of 1sec for a Thread sleep time of 10 sec

`System clock = 10:00:00` and `Recorded in Thread = 10:00:00` and `Difference = null`

Thread sleeps for 10sec

`System clock = 10:00:11` and `Recorded in Thread = 10:00:11` and `Difference = 11` `offset=0` as it is within permissible limit 10 +- 1

Thread sleeps for 10 sec and sys clock increased by 1 hour

`System clock = 11:00:21` and `Recorded in Thread = 11:00:21` and `Difference = 3600`
`offset = 3599`

now you need to subtract this offset and you will get 10:00:22 not accurate but close.

Comment: What do you mean by "checks the time"?

Comment: I read the question wrong so was to delete the post it is not appropriate here

Answer (score 0):

Or you can read time launching the "date" like this

```
Runtime.exec("date").getInputStream() ...
```